# Row Selection with checkbox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am receiving an object reference error with this code, not sure why.
I want to select the row in the datagridview with a checkbox selection, so if multiple rows are checked all the checked rows should appear as selected.
Below is the code that I have, but it receiving an object reference error when executing.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rowsel in dataGridView1.Rows)
{                
    if ((bool)(rowsel.Cells[Selectchkbox.Name].Value) == true)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowsel.Index].Selected = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowsel.Index].Selected = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me, just tested. The only guess is that column named Selectchkbox.Name does not exist in DataGridView. You should supply the string or number in the brackets:

```
rowsel.Cells["CheckBoxColumnNameOrIndex"].Value
```

Comment: I am receiving the same error even with the Checkbox column name.

Comment: The object reference is being thrown at   if ((bool)(rowsel.Cells[Selectchkbox.Name].Value) == true)